# Complex INNER JOIN SQL request

Tags: sql, join

I have a complex INNER JOIN SQL request I can't wrap my head around.  I was hoping someone could help me.  It involves 3 tables, so it has 2 inner joins.

My database has the tables "users", "statement", "opinion".

Users can author statements and opinions.
Opinions have an "authorid" variable referencing the id of the user who they represent, and they have a "statementid" variable referencing the statement they refer to.

I am trying to submit a request where, given 2 statements, I can return the list of users who have authored opinions about both statements.

I'm thinking something like

```
$sid1=5;
$sid2=6;
$sql = "
        SELECT user.*
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN opinion
        ON opinion.authorid=user.uid 
        WHERE opinion.statementid=  [sid1?  how can i use both]
        INNER JOIN statement
        ON statment.uid=opinion.statementid
        ";
```

But as you can see I am stuck.  Do I need a UNION?  Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I figured out how to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.uid
FROM users
JOIN opinion o, opinion o2
WHERE users.uid = o.authorid
AND users.uid = o2.authorid
AND o2.statementid = $sid2
AND o.statementid = $sid1
```

Comment: SELECT... JOIN..ON...JOIN...ON...WHERE...IN(...)...GROUP BY...HAVING COUNT(*) = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.uid
FROM users
JOIN opinion o, opinion o2
WHERE users.uid = o.authorid
AND users.uid = o2.authorid
AND o2.statementid = $sid2
AND o.statementid = $sid1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT user.*
  FROM opinion o 
  JOIN usrs u 
       ON u.uid = o.author_id
      AND o.statement_id = $sid1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT DISTINCT user.*
  FROM opinion o 
  JOIN usrs u 
       ON u.uid = o.author_id
      AND o.statement_id = $sid2
```

Don't have INTERSECT available in your SQL dialect?

```
SELECT A.* FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT user.*
  FROM opinion o 
  JOIN usrs u 
       ON u.uid = o.author_id
      AND o.statement_id = $sid1
) A
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT user.*
  FROM opinion o 
  JOIN usrs u 
       ON u.uid = o.author_id
      AND o.statement_id = $sid2
) B on A.uid = B.uid
```

Comment: I could not get either of these to work even after fixing the syntax, aka changing author_id to authorid, statement_id to statementid, and usrs to users... what could I be doing wrong?  I feel like I must be making some kind of stupid mistake....

Comment: @George: More details of the error, and less nit-picking of my typing would be useful.

Comment: I'm not nitpicking the typing i'm just trying to point out that the reason it isn't working isn't due to misspellings of variables.  I'm not sure how to get an error message since I'm using PHP and it just doesn't run when the SQL query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to link it twice.

```
SELECT user.*
FROM users u. opinion o1, statement s1
     , opinion o2, statement s2 
WHERE o1.authorid=user.uid 
AND o2.authorid = user.uid
AND o1.statement_id = s1.sid
AND o2.statementid = s2.sid
AND s1.sid = $sid1
AND s2.sid = $sid2
```

Comment: I could not get that to work.  I also fixed the s1.sid and s2.sid (statements have a uid, not an sid).  This solution looks the most understandable to me though.  I wish it would work...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query that you want:

```
   SELECT u.*
   from opinion o join
        users u
        on o.authorid = u.uid join
        statement s
        on o.statementid = s.sid
   where s.sid in (<list of statement ids>);
```

Your description of the data structure is a little bit confusing.  But I am guessing that `opinion`s having authors and statements are the key relationships (and that `statement` does not have a separate user ids associated with it).

Comment: statement has a user id associated with it, but that is the user who created the statement.

Comment: I could not get this to work even by changing s.sid to s.uid (statements have uid, not sid)... any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I did just get it to work but I am not sure it is producing the answer I had in mind...